# Optimal control problem proving extremum

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Let's consider the integral $F(x) = \int_{1}^{e}(x-t\dot{x})dt$, with initial conditions $x(1) = 1, x(e) = 2$. The problem is to find extremum of the integral above.
My approach: I was able to find function $\hat{x} = \frac{1+e}{2}ln(t) - \frac{t}{2} + \frac{3}{2}$ by standard technique using Eulers equation, but I don't understand how to prove whether this function is a maximum or a minimum of $F(x)$. I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: So $\dot{x}$ can be chosen freely, as long as the boundary conditions are met? Also can you elaborate a bit more on your approach, I assume with Euler's equation you mean [Euler-Lagrange's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)?

Comment: Is the expression for $F$ correct? As it stands, the Euler-Lagrange equation for it is $1+1=0$, which has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a typo in your question, since the Euler-Lagrange equation of the functional
$$
F[x] = \int_{1}^{e}(x-t\dot{x})\,dt \tag{1}
$$
is $1+1=0$, which has no solution. On the other hand, the function you found, $\hat{x}(t)=\frac{1+e}{2}\ln(t)-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{3}{2}$, is the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation of
$$
\tilde{F}[x]=\int_1^e(x-t\dot{x}^2)\,dt \tag{2}
$$
satisfying the boundary conditions $x(1)=1, x(e)=2$,
so I'll assume that $(2)$ is the correct functional. Now, let me answer your question.

Let $\eta(\cdot)$ be a sufficiently well-behaved function satisfying the boundary conditions $\eta(1)=\eta(e)=0$, so that $x=\hat{x}+\eta$ satisfy the boundary conditions of the question. Then
\begin{align}
\tilde{F}[\hat{x}+\eta]-\tilde{F}[\hat{x}]&=\int_1^e[\eta-t(2\dot{\hat{x}}\dot{\eta}+\dot{\eta}^2)]\,dt \\
&=\left.-2t\dot{\hat{x}}\eta\,\right|_1^{e}+\int_1^{e}\left[1+\frac{d}{dt}(2t\dot{\hat{x}})\right]\eta\,dt-\int_1^{e}t\dot{\eta}^2\,dt. \tag{3}
\end{align}
The first term on the RHS of $(3)$ vanishes because of the boundary conditions satisfied by $\eta$; the second term also vanishes, because $\hat{x}$ satisfies the Euler -Lagrange equation of $\tilde{F}$. Therefore,
$$
\tilde{F}[\hat{x}+\eta]-\tilde{F}[\hat{x}]=-\int_1^{e}t\dot{\eta}^2\,dt\leq 0, \tag{4}
$$
which implies that $\tilde{F}$ has a maximum at $\hat{x}$.